# Not able to create databases using MySQL configuration inside docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have installed Ubuntu using virtual box and also install apt, docker and docker-compose inside it.
Now I want to create MySQL database using docker-compose.yml 
In which, i defined MySQL configuration including imported database file.
When i execute following command it install MySQL but not create database.

```
sudo docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build
```

docker-compose.yml

```
mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    network_mode: "bridge"
    volumes:
      - ${DATA_ROOT}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${ENV_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER="${ENV_USER}"
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD="${ENV_PASSWORD}"
      - MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=0.0.0.0
      - MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT=3306
    command:
      - --user=root
      - --max_allowed_packet=500M
      - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
      - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      - --max_connections=250
      - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Also in some cases it allow me to create first time but when i remove whole image and volume in docker and try to recreate again then it given same issue.

I suppose there is some pre-installed file which restrict me to recreate it.(It's just my assumption)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove data directory  `- ${DATA_ROOT}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`  if you want to initialize database with `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` as clearly mentioned in [offical documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

**Usage against an existing database**

> If you start your mysql container instance with a data directory that
>   already contains a database (specifically, a mysql subdirectory), the
>   $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable should be omitted from the run command
>   line; it will in any case be ignored, and the pre-existing database
>   will not be changed in any way.

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer. But i already tried this thing of remove data directory but it doesn't work. And for second portion, I try to create MySQL after remove image and also prune volume in docker.

Comment: just the mount path, then `docker-compose rm -f && docker-compose up` is enough

Comment: I also do that but it also not worked. I tried lot many things which are not working that's why i place this question suppose i missed something at time of reading docs. But thank yo so much for given an answer.

Comment: okay seems like the asnwer did not help in your case but it common issue that I posted the answer for, let me delete the answer.